# SQL вложенный запрос

Tags: sql

Допустим есть 2 таблицы: "Названия" и "Категории"

У "Названия" есть 3 поля: id,name,category
У "Категории" есть 2 поля: id,name

В таблице "Названия" под полями category хранится id из таблицы "Категории", например

1 | Продукт1 | 1

2 | Продукт2 | 1

**А в категории:**

1 | Категория1

2 | Категория2

Теперь нужно вытащить все записи из таблицы "Названия", но чтобы поле category было заменено названием категории из таблицы "Категории", т.е

1 | Продукт1 | Категория1

2 | Продукт2 | Категория1

Comment: @release, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На коленке:

```
SELECT n.id, n.name, c.name 
  FROM Названия AS n INNER JOIN Категории AS c ON n.category = c.id
```

Вообще это базовые вещи...